# Declaring multiple service dependency in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I have declared dependency on 2 services in my controller like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngDropdowns']);  


app.controller('InventoryCaptureCtrl', 
     ['$scope', 'DataStoreService','VMInterfaceService',
     function($scope, DataStoreService, VMInterfaceService) {..}
```

But its throwing me -  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function`  at above declaration. what is the problem?

Here is my complte JS:

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['ngDropdowns']);  

  app.controller('InventoryCaptureCtrl', ['$scope', 'DataStoreService','VMInterfaceService',
    function($scope, DataStoreService, VMInterfaceService) {

// By default the 'text' property will be used as the display text in the dropdown entry.
// All options that are not dividers must have a 'text' property.
// Or you can specify a different property name via the dropdown-item-label attribute.
//
// If an options object has an 'href' property set, then that dropdown entry
//   will behave as a link and cannot be selected.
$scope.ddSelectOptions = [{
  text: 'Option1',
  iconCls: 'someicon'
}, {
  text: 'Option2',
  someprop: 'somevalue'
}, {
  text: 'Option2',
  someprop: 'somevalue'
}, {
  text: 'Option2',
  someprop: 'somevalue'
}, {
  text: 'Option2',
  someprop: 'somevalue'
}, ];

$scope.ddSelectOptionsType = [{
  text: 'Option1',
  iconCls: 'someicon'
}, {
  text: 'Option2',
  someprop: 'somevalue'
}, {
  text: 'Option2',
  someprop: 'somevalue'
}, {
  text: 'Option2',
  someprop: 'somevalue'
}, {
  text: 'Option2',
  someprop: 'somevalue'
}, ];

$scope.ddSelectSelected = {
  "text": "Select a Category"
}; // Must be an object
$scope.ddSelectSelectedType = {
  "text": "Select a Type"
}; // Must be an object

DataStoreService.initService();
$scope.items = DataStoreService.list();
console.log($scope.items);

var original = {
    itemCategory:null,itemName:null,
    itemPrice:null,purchaseDate:null,applianceType:null,
    insStatus:null,id:null
};
$scope.newitem = angular.copy(original);

$scope.saveItem = function() {
  alert("add new");
  $scope.newitem.itemCategory = $scope.ddSelectSelected.text;
  $scope.newitem.applianceType = $scope.ddSelectSelectedType.text;
  DataStoreService.save($scope.newitem);
  //$scope.newitem = {};
}

$scope.calculateScore = function(){
  alert("calculateScore" + id);
  VMInterfaceService.calculateScore(id);
}

$scope.delete = function(id) {
  alert(id);
  DataStoreService.delete(id);
  if ($scope.newitem.id == id) $scope.newitem = {};
}

$scope.edit = function(id) {
  $scope.newitem = angular.copy(DataStoreService.get(id));
}
  }
  ]);
```

Comment: Are you closing the controller with ]); ?

Comment: I have added plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/zBw5p7ZTqCKGTv0l6Tx9?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
app.controller('InventoryCaptureCtrl', 
    ['$scope', 'DataStoreService','VMInterfaceService',
    function($scope, DataStoreService, VMInterfaceService) {..

}]); // => '}' close function, ']' close array and ')' close method call
```